# How to set link_to (just a normal <a href>) to be clickable through a clickable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a div which is clickable (it is a collapse) and a link on top of it:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#w_abcd" class="collapsed">
                 <table class="table-condensed w">
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="col-sm-2">abcd</td>
                             <td class="col-sm-2">aaa</td>
                             <td class="col-sm-2">bbb</td>
                             <td class="col-sm-2">
                                 <a href="/ws/52b0f6a676646503c9000000">Show</a>
                             </td>
                             <td class="col-sm-2">
                                 <a href="/ws/52b0f6a676646503c9000000/edit">Edit</a>
                             </td>
                             <td class="col-sm-2">
                                 <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/ws/52b0f6a676646503c9000000" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
                 </a>
            </h4>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="w_abcd" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">aaa</div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">bbb</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#w_1234" class="collapsed"><table class="table-condensed w"><tbody><tr><td class="col-sm-2">1234</td><td class="col-sm-2">abcd</td><td class="col-sm-2">12311</td><td class="col-sm-2"><a href="/ws/52b0f83076646503c9010000">Show</a></td><td class="col-sm-2"><a href="/ws/52b0f83076646503c9010000/edit">Edit</a></td><td class="col-sm-2"><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/ws/52b0f83076646503c9010000" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td></tr></tbody></table></a></h4>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="w_1234" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">abcd</div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">12311</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6cA6L/

how to execute the link following and not the UI js (collapse) when clicking on the link? So how to click thwough the clickable div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('tr a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

when u click on the link,the event is propagated to parent, first you need to stop the event bubbling up the parent

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cA6L/2/)

Comment: thats working now! But with one problem: if I click the link (`Show`, `Edit`) and so go to the `Show` or `Edit` page, then click back in browser, the `e.stopPropagation()` trick doesn't work anymore. What could be the problem? I put the `e.stopPropagation()` in the `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` inside

Comment: in fiddle it is working ,check once ,may be some other js is working on it